# Fastest way to get the vertex an object intersects another object in THREE?

Tags: three.js

I have a model comprised of millions of vertices and I'd like to know the fastest way of checking whether a sphere geometry intersects the model as it moves around the scene (e.g. the first point of contact) with the exact position (x, y, z).

Comment: That sounds like a nightmare. You'd have to take each face, construct a [`Plane`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Plane) to represent it, and then use [`Plane.intersectsSphere`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Plane.intersectsSphere). You could potentially reduce the search time by grouping your faces using an Octree, and checking for intersections with your sphere.

Comment: This question is probably too broad for SO (try [three.js forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/)) but (1) do a check against the model's bounding sphere or box first, (2) only compare vertex distance from sphere if that passes, (3) use more complex data structures like an [octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) if checking each vertex is too slow.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy I skipped discussing vertex checking simply because a sphere could intersect the model _before_ it encompasses any vertices. While I don't think the topic its self is too broad, I'd agree it doesn't belong here without further effort from Detuned (attempted code, encountered errors, etc.)